# Loop problems with Telegram bot

Tags: node.js, api, telegram

I'm currently developping a telegram bot.

Here's my code:

```
bot.command('check', ctx => {
console.log(ctx.from.id, ctx.chat.id)
var files = getFilesFromDir("toSend", [".txt"])
if(files.length > 0){

  for (i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    const url = 'https://api.telegram.org/bot'+bot_token+'/sendDocument'

    let r = request(url, (err, res, body) => {
        if(err) console.log(err)
        console.log(body)
    })
    console.log(files[i])
    let f = r.form()
    f.append('chat_id', '476090013')
    f.append('document', fs.createReadStream("tosend/"+files))
  }
}else{
  console.log('r')
}
})
```

My problems is the loop, I tried the `for` but I can't figured out.

I have a folder named `tosend`, I want that every file in there to be transfered to telegram api.

For one file it's working but if in the folder there are more than one file, `f.append('document', fs.createReadStream("tosend/"+files))` the +files take every name instead of one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to create a stream from an array of files: `+files` (which will return a comma separated string with all the filenames).

You need to use `files[i]` to create a stream per file.

```
f.append('document', fs.createReadStream("tosend/" + files[i]))
```